# Getting an error when starting ruby irb in a rclone mounted volume on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, irb, rclone

When I am in a mounted share on Linux I get the following error when starting a ruby program or just irb. As long as I am outside the share everything works fine. The share is a mounted by rclone. Maybe its rclone specific. For irb the error is:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1042:in `block in find_by_path'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `find'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1041:in `find_by_path'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:212:in `try_activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:150:in `block in search_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:158:in `block in each_localized_path'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:167:in `each_sublocale'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:157:in `each_localized_path'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:145:in `search_file'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:124:in `find'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:108:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb:32:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/init.rb:113:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/init.rb:113:in `init_config'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/init.rb:17:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:378:in `start'
from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the same error with `irb --simple-prompt` ?

Comment: @Nifriz: Yes, makes no difference.

Comment: Does `gem` works? If yes, try this `sudo gem update --system`

Comment: @Nifriz: Did the update, no difference.

Comment: Do you do a directory rename or creation before using `pwd` command?

Comment: @Nifriz: No and I do not use pwd explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your assumptions:

- Do you have proper permissions for the share?
- Can you run `pwd` from the mounted share?
- Do you have a pot of coffee as well as a vile of hemlock in case things go south?